# Unrecognized selector error while setting a property of instance of custom UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

In a project (XCode 4, iOS 5, with ARC) I have a subclass of UIView with a boolean property:

```
 // Diagram.h
 @interface Diagram : UIView 
 @property (assign) BOOL  flag;
 @end

 // Diagram.m
 @implementation Diagram
 @synthesize flag; 
 ...
```

In the main view controller:

```
 // ViewController.h
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet Diagram *schema;
 ...

 // ViewController.m
 @synthesize schema;
 ...
 schema.flag = NO;
 ...
```

The last line causes this error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setFlag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb07e660'
```

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: In my case, the problem was I had not set my custom class to my view controller!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

Diagram.m was not listed in target > Build Phases > Compile Sources.

Answer (score 4):

When laying out the view for `ViewController` make sure that the Identity inspector identifies your view as a `Diagram` rather than a `UIView` and that the correct view is linked to the `schema` outlet in your controller.

Currently, the runtime thinks that `schema` is a plain `UIView`, according to the error message.

Comment: The Identity inspector identifies correctly my view as Diagram.

Comment: In the NIB > Connection Inspector > Outlets, schema is connected to Diagram.

Comment: A test: in 'viewDidLoad:` in the view controller, put `NSLog(@"schema: %@", self.schema);` to see what kind of object is being created when the nib is loaded.

Comment: Test result: schema: <UIView: 0xb8cf520; frame = (6 277; 350 393); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xb8cff20>>

Comment: So, clearly there is some connection or property in the nib that's not quite right but it's hard to guess beyond the things you've already checked.  Does that frame match the view you expect to have connected to `schema`?

Comment: The only strange thing I see in NIB (actually the storyboard), in the connection inspector of view controller, is that "view" is connected with View (black) and (another) View (this time gray).

Answer (score 0):

In your view XIB (where is the Diagram), click on the diagram view.

In the right panel, select the third tab, then you can change the object class (first field named "custom class"). Actually, it should be UIView. Set it to "Diagram".